Can't access HDD External
So I have 2 HDD external that can't be accessed
Both showing at devices and printer
But doesn't show at computer
In devices and printer it says BUP portable and expansion but I can't access both
Light indicator at HDD External is on
BUP fail after fail chkdsk x: /f /r /x stuck at stage 5 60% after I restart can't access it anymore
List disk or even partition tool and defragler can't detect the disk
Need help thanks a lot

It looks as if these disks are defective. While it may be possible to recover part of your files with a lot of work, the fastest and easiest way is to just restore from backup to new disks and just use these.

How to open the disk. I mean it only show as bup portable and not showing any drive letter or in disk management. Is there anyway to force mount it. Thanks

You can not open it. You will need to try and to image it (e.g. with ddrescue), try to fix the filesystem issues and maybe get some files back - this will take many hours or days or weeks of work. I wouldn't bother - it's nearly always fast to just restore from backup.
